# Adonisjs updating user profile

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I'm trying to update auth user profile but it's errors Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'user') on auth.correct.user
I'm new in node.js so i really don't understand why i'm getting this error.

```
public async update({ request, auth, response }) {
        try {
            const user = auth.correct.user
            user.firstName = request.input('firstName')
            user.lastName = request.input('lastName')
            user.email = request.input('email')
            user.password = request.input('password')

            await user.save()

            return response.json({
                status: 'success',
                message: 'Profile updated!',
                data: user
            })
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

I can't get auth user...

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that the user is **authenticated** to use the `auth.user` object.

These example is quiet interesting : https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/auth/web-guard#authenticate-subsequent-requests

### Steps to get user

#### Check that the authentication is successful :

```
await auth.use('web').authenticate()
```

#### Access the `user` object

```
let user = auth.use('web').user
```

### What this error means:

The error say that the property you try to access (`user`) is from a undefined object (`correct`).

If you want to debug your code (to see what append and what's variable values) you can enable node debugging or add some (`console.info(<the variable>)`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about `auth.correct.user` existence.
Using lucid perspective with transactional database, I can answer using this code.

```js
const Database = use('Database')
const User = use('App/Models/User')

async update({ request, auth, response }) {
    const user = await User.find(auth.user.id)
    if (!user) {
        return response.status(404).json({
            status: 'failed',
            message: 'Profile not found'
        })
    }
    
    const trx = await Database.beginTransaction()
    try {
        const { firstName, lastName, email, password } = request.all()
        
        user.firstName = firstName
        user.lastName = lastName
        user.email = email
        user.password = password
        await user.save(trx)
        await trx.commit()

        return response.status(200).json({
            status: 'success',
            message: 'Profile updated!',
            data: user.toJSON()
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('update user', error)
        await trx.rollback()
        return response.status(500).json({
            status: 'error',
            message: error.message
        })
    }
}
```